# Event Listener in Android Service Seems to stop

Tags: java, android, service, notifications, event-listener

I have a service that listens for an event posted by a Particle Photon (microcontroller) and then gives a notification to the user. The event listener is registered when the Service is started in the onStartCommand function in a separate thread (Because the action requires that it not be started in the main thread) Everything works fine even when the app isn't running but after about 5 minutes it just stops. The service from what I can tell is never destroyed (I have it display something if it gets destroyed and it never has) so my gut feeling is the event listener stops working. Any help would be appreciated! The code is below!

*Note: Event listener does use an internet connection if that is of any consequence*

**Service Code below:**

```
public class NotificationService extends Service implements ParticleEventHandler{


//private long weightChangeSubscriptionID;
private long lockedChangeSubscriptionID;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    final String deviceID;
    final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("justintime.com.productscale", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    deviceID = sharedPreferences.getString("deviceID"," ");

    ParticleCloudSDK.init(this);

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                if(!deviceID.equals(" ")) {
                    //weightChangeSubscriptionID = ParticleCloudSDK.getCloud().subscribeToDeviceEvents("weightChange", deviceID, NotificationService.this);
                    lockedChangeSubscriptionID = -1;
                    lockedChangeSubscriptionID = ParticleCloudSDK.getCloud().subscribeToDeviceEvents("lockWtChange", deviceID, NotificationService.this);
                    if(lockedChangeSubscriptionID != -1){
                        sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("serviceRunning", true).apply();
                    }
                }
                else
                    Log.w("Error", "Not started! Possible no deviceID available");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("justintime.com.productscale", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //try {
                //ParticleCloudSDK.getCloud().unsubscribeFromEventWithID(weightChangeSubscriptionID);
                //ParticleCloudSDK.getCloud().unsubscribeFromEventWithID(lockedChangeSubscriptionID);
                sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("serviceRunning", false).apply();
                Log.w("Subsction", "unsibscribed from lockedWeightchange");
            //} catch (ParticleCloudException e) {
            //    e.printStackTrace();
            //}
        }
    });
    t.start();

    super.onDestroy();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}



@Override
public void onEventError(Exception e) {
    Log.wtf("error", "error on event");
}

@Override
public void onEvent(String eventName, ParticleEvent particleEvent) {

    //if(eventName.equals("weightChange")) {
    //    DisplayActivity.updateScaleReading();
    //}


    if(eventName.equals("lockWtChange")) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.scale)
                .setContentTitle("Scale change!")
                .setContentText("Scales Value Has Changed While Locked!!")
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{500, 1000, 500})
                .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_EVENT)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
                .setColor(Color.GREEN);

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainScreen.class);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainScreen.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);

        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1234, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

}

I am running the service from the main activity by checking if it is already running or not and then running it using the following code: (It is also run on boot using a boot reciever class)

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    updateScaleReading();
    updateLockValue();
    subscribeToEvents();

    if (!isMyServiceRunning()){
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), justintime.com.productscale.NotificationService.class);
        getApplicationContext().startService(serviceIntent);
    }else{
        Log.w("Service", "Service is already running!");
    }
}
```

**isMyServiceRunning() function:**

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("justintime.com.productscale", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    //return sharedPreferences.getBoolean("serviceRunning", false);
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (NotificationService.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Manifest File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/scale_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/scale_launcher"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainScreen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".DisplayActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <activity android:name=".SelectionActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <service android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name=".NotificationService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="justintime.com.productscale.NotificationService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <receiver
        android:name=".BootReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="BootReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

Comment: Does it continue to run after 5 min if the app is active (in the foreground)?

Comment: did you add the Service to the manifest file ?

Comment: @Ben_Gratvol he did mention the service is started and running for about 5 min before it stops doing anything.

Comment: @Ben_Gratvol Yes and the manifest file has been added if you want to take a look

Comment: @LightYearsBehind It does appear that notifications run fine while the app is in the foreground but when in the background or completely closed it stops working after about 5-10 min